# OpenGL 4.5 Shader - Are my input buffers corrupting each other?

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, vertex

I have a problem on setting up two buffers for my shaders. I wanted to use Compute Shader, but the problem already starts in the Vertex Shader.

**What I want**: Two separate SSBO with particles inside that I can spin nd move individually.

**How I want to start**: Just put the initial values into VAOs, copy them into a SSBO in the vertex shader and process them in the Computer Shaders.

**Problem**: Both VAOs are created equally and the values are equal. However, when I want to copy the values into a SSBO the VAO breaks and only 512 values (which is half of the number of items) are further correct and the others partly have weird different values, what I can see from RenderDoc.

Have a look in my application.cpp

```
#include "application.hpp"

application::application()
{
    this->initParticleSystem();
}    

void application::initParticleSystem()
{
    this->initializeWindow();
    this->initializeOpenGL();
}

void application::runThread()
{
    double lastFPStime = glfwGetTime();
    int frameCounter = 0;

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(m_RenderWindow))
    {
        this->run(frameCounter, lastFPStime);
    }
}

void application::initializeWindow()
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        throw runtime_error("\n[ERROR] GLFW initialization failed!\n");
    }

    this->setupRenderWindow();

    /// set key callback
    this->setupKeyCallBack();

    IOManager::getInstance()->setRenderWindow(m_RenderWindow);
}


void application::initializeOpenGL()
{
    Log::logInit(m_Name, "OpenGL");
    glewInit();

    if (!glewIsSupported("GL_VERSION_4_6"))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("\n[ERROR] Sorry, but you need an OpenGL 4.6 Core to run this program.\n");
    }
    /// get version info 
    Log::printSystemSettings();

    this->initBuffers();
    this->initBasicShader();
    this->initComputeShader();
}

void application::initBuffers()
{
    this->packVec4GridSizeSSBO(VORTEX_1_SEEDS_NR, SHADER_GRID_VOR_1_NR, m_GridPositionVaoHandle, m_PackedGridBufferHandle, { 0.,0. }, "Grid");
    this->packVec4GridSizeSSBO(VORTEX_2_SEEDS_NR, SHADER_GRID_VOR_2_NR, m_VortexPositionVaoHandle, m_PackedVortexBufferHandle, { 0.,-0. }, "Vortex");

    this->bindBuffers();
}


void application::initComputeShader()
{
    this->initComputeShader(GRID_VELOCITY_NR, GRID_VELOCITY_SHADER);
}
void application::bindBuffers()
{
    this->bindVertexBufferObject(VORTEX_1_SEEDS_NR, m_PackedGridBufferHandle, "Vortex 1");
    this->bindVertexBufferObject(VORTEX_2_SEEDS_NR, m_PackedVortexBufferHandle, "Vortex 2");
}

void application::bindVertexBufferObject(unsigned int index, uint32_t &bufferHandle, string text)
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferHandle);
    glVertexAttribPointer(index, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(index);
}

void application::packVec4GridSizeSSBO(unsigned int seedNumber, unsigned int shaderPosNumber, uint32_t &vaoHandle, uint32_t &packedBufferHandle, vec2f translate, string text)
{
    constexpr ptrdiff_t ssboSize = sizeof(glm::vec4) * GRID_DIM_SQ;
    constexpr ptrdiff_t packedBufferSize = ssboSize;
    ptrdiff_t ssboOffset = 0;
    this->initSeeds(packedBufferSize, ssboSize, packedBufferHandle, translate, text);
    this->bindBufferToVertexArrayObject(vaoHandle, packedBufferHandle, seedNumber);

    glBindBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, shaderPosNumber, packedBufferHandle, ssboOffset, ssboSize);     /// Grid Positions
}
void application::bindBufferToVertexArrayObject(uint32_t &vaoHandle, uint32_t &bufferHandle, unsigned int seedNumber)
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoHandle);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoHandle);
}

void application::initBasicShader()
{
    glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE);

    uint32_t vertex_shader_handle = IOManager::getInstance()->loadShader(PARTICLE_VERTEX_SHADER, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    uint32_t fragment_shader_handle = IOManager::getInstance()->loadShader(PARTICLE_FRAGMENT_SHADER, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    m_RenderProgramHandle = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(m_RenderProgramHandle, fragment_shader_handle);
    glAttachShader(m_RenderProgramHandle, vertex_shader_handle);
    glLinkProgram(m_RenderProgramHandle);

    IOManager::getInstance()->checkProgramLinked(m_RenderProgramHandle, string(PARTICLE_VERTEX_SHADER) + ", " + string(PARTICLE_FRAGMENT_SHADER));

    glDeleteShader(vertex_shader_handle);
    glDeleteShader(fragment_shader_handle);
}

void application::initComputeShader(int index, string filePath)
{
    uint32_t computeShaderHandle = IOManager::getInstance()->loadShader(filePath, GL_COMPUTE_SHADER);
    m_ParticleShaders[index] = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(m_ParticleShaders[index], computeShaderHandle);
    glLinkProgram(m_ParticleShaders[index]);

    IOManager::getInstance()->checkProgramLinked(m_RenderProgramHandle, filePath);
    Log::printProgramLog(m_ParticleShaders[index]);

    /// delete shader as we're done with them.
    glDeleteShader(computeShaderHandle);
}

void application::run(int &frameCounter, double &lastFPStime)
{
    this->runParticleSystem();

    IOManager::getInstance()->calculateTime(frameCounter, lastFPStime);
}

void application::runParticleSystem()
{
    /// process user inputs
    glfwPollEvents();

    /// step through the simulation if not PAUSED
    if (!paused)
    {
        glUseProgram(m_ParticleShaders[0]);

        /// Number of invocations #grid_x * grid_y
        glDispatchCompute(GRID_NUM_WORK_GROUPS, 1, 1);

        //@TODO: all shaders but the Integrate-Shader can run parallel and don't need the barrier bit in between!
        glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT);
        m_FrameNumber++;
    }

    this->runBasicShader();

    glfwSwapBuffers(m_RenderWindow);
}

void application::runOpenGLBuffer()
{
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPointSize(PARTICLE_SIZE);
}

void application::runBasicShader()
{
    this->runOpenGLBuffer();
    glUseProgram(m_RenderProgramHandle);

    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, NUM_PARTICLES);
}

void application::initSeeds(ptrdiff_t packedBufferSize, ptrdiff_t positionSSBOSize, uint32_t &bufferHandle, vec2f translate, string text)
{
    vector<glm::vec4> initialSeed(GRID_DIM_SQ);

    for (int j = 0; j < GRID_DIM; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < GRID_DIM; i++) {

            int index = j * GRID_DIM + i;

            /// Normalize positions for GPU to -1 <= xyPos <= 1
            vec2f shaderPos = Utils::grid2ShaderDim(vec2i{ i, j });

            initialSeed[index].x = shaderPos.x + translate.x;
            initialSeed[index].y = shaderPos.y + translate.y;
            initialSeed[index].z = index;  /// Index of grid cell
            initialSeed[index].w = 1;
        }
    }

    this->saveDataInBuffer(packedBufferSize, positionSSBOSize, initialSeed, bufferHandle);
}

void application::saveDataInBuffer(ptrdiff_t packed_buffer_size, ptrdiff_t ssbo_size, vector<glm::vec4> dataVector, uint32_t &bufferHandle)
{
    void* initialData = malloc(packed_buffer_size);
    memset(initialData, 0, packed_buffer_size);
    memcpy(initialData, dataVector.data(), ssbo_size);

    glGenBuffers(1, &bufferHandle);
    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, bufferHandle);
    glBufferStorage(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, packed_buffer_size, initialData, GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);

    free(initialData);
}
```

... and my very basic vertex shader.glsl:

```
#version 460
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable

// ---- INPUT -----------------------------------
layout (location = 0) in vec4 in_VortexPosition1; 
layout (location = 1) in vec4 in_VortexPosition2; 

// ---- OUTPUT ----------------------------------
layout (location = 0) out flat uint out_PosIndex;

out gl_PerVertex
{
    vec4 gl_Position;
};

// ---- UNIFORM ---------------------------------
layout(std430, binding = 6) buffer grid_vortex1_block
{
    vec4 gridVortex1[];
};

layout(std430, binding = 7) buffer grid_vortex2_block
{
    vec2 gridVortex2[];
};

void main ()
{
    out_PosIndex = uint(in_VortexPosition1.z);

    // only half the values
    gl_Position = vec4(gridVortex2[out_PosIndex].xy, 0, 1);

    // works fine
    //gl_Position = vec4(gridVortex1[out_PosIndex].xy, 0, 1);
}
```

And the Compute Shader.glsl:

```
#version 460

#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable

#define WORK_GROUP_SIZE 128

layout (local_size_x = WORK_GROUP_SIZE) in;

// ---- UNIFORM ---------------------------------
layout(std430, binding = 6) buffer grid_vortex1_block
{
    vec4 gridVortex1[];
};

layout(std430, binding = 7) buffer grid_vortex2_block
{
    vec2 gridVortex2[];
};
void main()
{
    uint INDEX = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;

// THIS OPERATION SCREWS UP EVERYTHING IN THE BUFFER, as you can see in pic3
    gridVortex1[INDEX].xy += 0.2f;
    gridVortex1[INDEX].xy -= 0.2f;

}
```

The following two pictures show the result. First, correct grid (e.g. vortex 1, not spinning yet), second, the half disappears after one frame for vortex 2.

Thank you for your help.

[image: vortex1]
[image: vortex2]

Comment: "*Just put the initial values into VAOs, copy them into a SSBO in the vertex shader and process them in the Computer Shaders.*" Why not just use the buffers themselves as SSBOs? Why are you copying from vertex data, when the CS could just read those buffers itself?

Comment: I had the issue with the compute shaders before and tried to reduce it to the problem. Now I added the shader again. The problem with the SSBO that is filled from the application is the one that you can see in pic3. A simple operation + and -  again messes up everything. I have not the slightest idea what is going on and just guess it might be some offsets or reserved storage space...

Comment: You're  dispatching `GRID_NUM_WORK_GROUPS`x`GRID_NUM_WORKGROUPS` in 2D, but only use `gl_GlobalInvocationID.x` as index to your buffers, so you will have `GRID_NUM_WORKGROUPS` parallel - and totally  incoherent and unsyncrhonized - accesses to the same buffer locations each.

Comment: That is pretty true, I corrected in my code and in the entry here. I don't get the flickering anymore. I still need the VAO now to have an index of the position of the display, that has to be displayed: `gl_Position = vec4(gridVortex2[out_PosIndex].xy, 0, 1);` - in earlier versions I could simply create an attribute, link it with glVertexAttribPointer and use it in the shader.

Comment: As far as I see I need to use a VAO (I am using SPRI-V shader) and give them a location. So, I still need the VAO. I stored the index in `in_VortexPosition1/2.z `equally. When I give the Vertex shader the `gridVortex1[in_VortexPosition1.z]` everything is fine. For `gridVortex2[in_VortexPosition]` the second half is missing, still.

Comment: Please do not talk about VAOs as if they store any data.

Comment: Well, the VAOs contain VBOs which contain the information about vertices etc.

Comment: Any idea about would could be the matter?